# Pegar informações de uma página gerada por JS com PHP

Tags: php

Tenho esta página que esta em um servidor onde nao tenho acesso.
https://genuncoin.com/crypto/
Abra ela no navegador evai ver que o jquery dela gera um número.

estou tentando pegar o número que ela gera mas quando utilizo esta função:

```
$page = file_get_contents('http://genuncoin.com/crypto/');
```

o `$page` me retorna o html dela sem o numero somente os javas scripts e html da tela.
alguém  saberia como pegar o valor que é gerado pelo javascript??

Answer (score 0):

os caracteres que estão sendo gerados estão na variável `balancebig` e ela é exibida na tela da seguinte forma:

```
$('#bnkPrice').text(balancebig);
```

Como você quer recuperar a informação dessa variável, sugiro que vc faça uma requisição ajax enviando o conteúdo dessa variável para seu script PHP. Um exemplo de como você poderia fazer isso é o seguinte:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'script.php',
    method: 'post',
    data: {variavel: balancebig},

    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        alert('Caracteres enviados');
    }
});
```

no seu arquivo (que para fins de exemplo estou usando `script.php` você pode recuperar o valor usando a superglobal post, como você faria normalmente:

```
$dado = $_POST['variavel'];
```

Comment: entao dessa forma ate vai mas preciso pegar com php e nao com ajax. pois desta forma consigo por num cron e salvar no banco a informação

Comment: Mas você está mandando para um script PHP. Chegando nesse script faça oq bem entender com esse valor, inclusive colocar no banco de dados.

Comment: mas tudo tem q ser por backend enao quando alguém acessar a pagina.

Comment: Isso não está fazendo sentido para mim. Se você tem acesso a página essa é a melhor forma de fazer. Se você não conseguir mudar o script do front você quer minerar dados na web. Ai fica um pouco mais complicado

Comment: Edite sua pergunta acrescentando exatamente o que você quer e como você quer chegar na solução

Comment: essa url esta em outro servidor e eu quero pegar com o meu php somente o que retorna mas c vc acessar ela o conteudo da div nao tem nada e eu nao consigo pegar com php e gravar so o numero no db quando eu puxo o get_gile la ele m traz tudo menos o resultado

Comment: Isso pq JavaScript roda na máquina do usuário file_get_contents lê o conteúdo de um arquivo e transforma em uma string. Logo não existe a informação que você quer no arquivo.